# How safe is it to use Gmail, Facebook, YouTube, Amazon on Public Wifi or more official Wifi such as Apple Store Wifi?

Tags: security, wireless-access-point, internet-security, public-wifi

First of all, somebody could be pretending to be the airport Wifi by setting the Wifi ID to be "Free Airport Wifi", so it might not be the "official Wifi".

And either it is "official" or "non-official" Wifi, is it very difficult for them to crack the encryption and pretend that they are you? (such as to send your friends or relatives a message that was not written by you).

The reason is that Gmail, Facebook, YouTube, Amazon (or even the banks), use HTTPS with the url: `https://` so would it take a very long time for them to decrypt it and pretend that they are you? (for example, if they have to use computing power that is worth a few thousand dollars to steal a few thousand dollars from you, they probably wouldn't do it). For one thing, if they really want to, the person hacking it doesn't need to listen in on the Wifi, but can be listening on the Internet backbone or node?

Comment: Hotel or Airport free Wireless is much less safe than Secured Wireless . That said, use Public WiFi (not Private) and make sure (Windows 10) that Defender is on along with Smart Screen to protect you. That is a reasonable, but not perfect, defense

Comment: It's perfectly safe to use public WiFi, provided your Common Sense 2019 Personal Edition is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) provides secure end-to-end encryption of all data being sent from your computer to the website.  Anyone in between the endpoints can only see encrypted data and will not be able to decrypt it.

In this respect, it is safe to use any website that *properly* uses HTTPS.  Browsers are also blocking or warning on [mixed content](https://www.howtogeek.com/443032/what-is-mixed-content-and-why-is-chrome-blocking-it/).

However, it is never wise to connect to WiFi unknown WiFi access points.  Once you are connected to them, they can read any unencrypted data being sent over them.  Additionally, a bad actor can be trying to use security vulnerabilities on your device to gain access.

Comment: I think you can decrypt HTTPS data -- it just takes too long... I don't know how long, but if it takes 2 years to decrypt that data, I don't think people would like to do it (unless it is critical).  If I connect to a Wifi in a cafe, maybe it is not as safe, but most sensitive data (Facebook / Gmail) are indeed through HTTPS... maybe the data that is not through HTTPS is like a website I look at, but usually those won't be sensitive data

Comment: @nopole - There are no known weaknesses to WAP2 at this time.

Comment: but what if that WAP2 is provided by some hackers pretending to be an official Wifi connection (such as "Free Airport Wifi" or "Apple Store Guest 2")

Comment: That is why Smart Screen is a good addition if you have Windows 10. It will pick up and warn / block fraudulent websites